# Maximum length of hexadecimal escape sequence

Tags: c++, hex, language-lawyer

Consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void print(const T& t) {
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned long long>(t) << " " << sizeof(t) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    auto cU = U'\xFFFFFFFF';
    auto cL = L'\xFFFFFFFF';
    auto cQ = '\xFFFFFFFF1'; // warning in gcc; error in clang
    print(cU);
    print(cL);
    print(cQ);
}
```

This code gives me a warning when compiled in [gcc](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cmoA94lRs1U9fKbX) and error with same text in in [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jMoeYZhKBHleU4Sw):

> hex escape sequence out of range

2.14.3/4 of C++14 Standard says:

> There is no limit to the number of digits in a hexadecimal sequence.

But simultanously contains a restrictions to possible type of character literal: `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t` or `char32_t`. This means that maximum size of possible type does not exceed 32 bits. I.e. maximum length of hex-sequence (only hex-digits part) is limited to 8.

My question is: Why Standard says about unlimited length of hex-sequence and how to use hex-sequence with more than 8 digits?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath if so, why limit length for octal-sequence?

Comment: Perhaps backward compatiblity? When C was invented, they only needed a single byte for octal-sequences. In a string `\1111` is octal `111` followed by the character `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler vendor might want to come up with an 8 byte character type, as an extension.

Placing a limitation to a character *literal* would prevent to initalize these types with a literal.

Comment: Any example of such compilers?

Comment: The standard tries to be as unrestrictive as possible. Just because there's no limit, it doesn't mean that there's a compiler out there that tries to do this (seemingly silly) thing.